# Google Trends data at county level

Tags: usa, county, search-engine, trends

Does anyone know how Washington Post has managed to source Google Trends data at **county** level for this map?

[image]

Here's a [state-level query](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=now%207-d&geo=US-KS&q=eclipse) for Kansas. The geographical response is by `metro`.

[image]

In the (unofficial) API response this data is labeled `interest_by_dma` (designated market area), which is more granular than state level, but less than county as per Washpost's map.

I've heard that Google does not sell Trends data. Assuming this is right and Washpost does not have some private arrangement, does anyone know how they might have sourced this data?

Comment: Very similar picture has been 
"created by the Google News lab using CartoDB [and]
published on August 1, 2017": [1](https://trends.google.com/trends/story/US_cu_YdGNpF0BAACx9M_en), [2](https://googledataorg.carto.com/u/googledata/viz/51003fc8-28bc-4ac8-9d30-3c430a19b0c1/embed_map).

Comment: Thanks @StanislavKralin. I'd hazard a guess the carto map is exactly the same source data with 7 classes instead of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't work for The Post or Google, and thus cannot speak authoritatively, I was at a Google event for top news organizations last year in NYC, and can attest to the fact that -- depending on the publication -- Google often provides custom Trends data as an enterprise service to publishers. That would be my guess here.

Comment: I think you're right - my understanding of Google's policy was wrong. Clearly some arrangement with (at least certain) news organisations, but not a service open to all.

Comment: Yes, Google has a tense but symbiotic relationship with news orgs generally, as it's largely their original content which is the chief driver of search. So they have special programs to keep publishers happy and to encourage them to create AMP versions of their content.